# Remove duplicates and add some column using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to do the followings using Python Pandas?

I have a csv file like the table A.

```
TABLE A
------------------------------------------------
Name               Email
------------------------------------------------
Hinckley Joel      hjoel@mail.com
Hinckley Joel      hjoel@mail.com 
Hinckley Joel      hinkleyjoel@mail.com
Joel Hinckley      hinkjoel@mail.com
Siegel Allison     sallison@mail.com
Nielsen Tami       ntami@mail.com
Nielsen Tami       ntami@gmail.com
...
```

I want to remove the rows with the duplicated name, also I want to add a new column "Secondary Email".
The secondary email will be the first email of the duplicated rows.

The final table I want to make is Table B.

```
TABLE B
-----------------------------------------------------------
Name               Email                   Secondary Email
-----------------------------------------------------------
Hinckley Joel      hjoel@mail.com          hinkleyjoel@mail.com
Siegel Allison     sallison@mail.com
Nielsen Tami       ntami@mail.com
```

As you can see from Table A and B, I want to consider as a same person even if the first and last name was replaced. (ex : "Hinckley Joel" and "Joel Hinckley")
Also, I want to take the secondary email (ex : hinkleyjoel@mail.com) and add it to the new column.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pivoting with two columns, but you need to remove duplicates:

```
(df.drop_duplicates()
   .assign(col=lambda x: x.groupby("Name").cumcount())
   .pivot(index='Name', columns='col', values='Email')
   .add_prefix('Email_').reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
col            Name            Email_0               Email_1
0     Hinckley Joel     hjoel@mail.com  hinkleyjoel@mail.com
1     Joel Hinckley  hinkjoel@mail.com                   NaN
2      Nielsen Tami     ntami@mail.com       ntami@gmail.com
3    Siegel Allison  sallison@mail.com                   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Quang Hoang.   
But your output table is a bit different with Table B.     
I want to remove "Joel Hinckley" because he is a same person with "Hinckley Joel".    
Do you have any idea to do it?

Comment: @ShiJ how do you know they are the same? based on the different order of the names? What about names that can be both first and last, like `Cohen Thompson` :-)

Comment: Almost names will be supposed to be composed of the first and last names. We will ignore the names if they contain any middle names.

Answer (score 2):

Not as pretty and tidy as @QuangHoang but the same concept:

```
df_dup = df.drop_duplicates()
df_out = df_dup.set_index(['Name', df_dup.groupby('Name')['Email'].cumcount()])
df_out = df_out.unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'Secondary Email' if j != 0 else f'{i}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            Name              Email       Secondary Email
0   Hinckley Joel     hjoel@mail.com  hinkleyjoel@mail.com
1   Joel Hinckley  hinkjoel@mail.com                   NaN
2    Nielsen Tami     ntami@mail.com       ntami@gmail.com
3  Siegel Allison  sallison@mail.com                   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

By use of `duplicated` and `simple masking` and `merger`:
But first, drop the duplicate rows since two rows can have same name and emial as you have mentioned in your question..

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
duplicates = df['Name'].duplicated()
df[~duplicates].merge(df[duplicates].drop_duplicates(subset=['Name']).rename(columns={'email':'second email'}), how='left')

               Name            email               second email
0     Hinckley Joel     hjoel@mail.com  hinkleyjoel@mail.com
1     Joel Hinckley  hinkjoel@mail.com                   NaN
2      Nielsen Tami     ntami@mail.com       ntami@gmail.com
```